# Having issues while loading the ExtJS based app with google feeds api

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-cmd, google-feed-api

Having issues while loading my app which is based on **ExtJS** and using **Sencha 5.1.3.61.** The problem seems to be in this file `ext/packages/ux/src/google/Feeds.js.`

Getting this error on app launch..

```
"?file=feeds&v=1.x&output=nocss%3Dtrue&async=2:1 Uncaught Error: Module:'feeds' not found!"
```

Any solution or work around can be helpful!!

Comment: I got same problems for loading google feeds.If you don't need ux package for your application then you can remove its reference from ext package.This solved my problem.Please post your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got resolved by replacing `requiresGoogle : {...}` with `_requiresGoogle : {...}`. Thats it.

Source : https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?334652-Google-Feed-API-deprecated/page2 .

Answer (score 0):

You can try overriding it, like:

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.ux.google.Feeds', {
    override: 'Ext.ux.google.Feeds',

    requiresGoogle: {}
});
```

Comment: tried this but not working.....made these changes in my feeds.js file. Do I need to make some other changes as well? I am new to ExtJS.